# How do I make HDParm or equivalent settings persist in Windows?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8.1, performance, hdparm

I have a laptop with a harddrive that spins down so aggressively (after ~10s of inactivity) that it causes performance problems in games and various other apps that have frequent but spread out drive accesses. The spin-up causes a two second pause in whatever app is initiating the disk access.

I've found a half-solution which is to use hdparm for windows to change the drive's spin down timeout. But the problem is if the system reboots or sleeps, that value gets lost, and I have to run hdparm again.

What would be a good solution to make this kind of fix permanent? I run hdparm via batch files right now, but that requires a security prompt click, so it can't really be properly automated. Is there a way to make the equivalent changes to the drive settings with some method other than hdparm?

Specifics:

Windows 8.1

MSI GS60 Ghost Pro 2PE-053

Hard drive in question is an HGST HTS721010A9E630 (Hitachi Travelstar 7k1000)

Comment: use task scheduler to start it without UAC prompt: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=135472

Comment: that *may* work, but is there a way to make the task run on resume from standby?

Comment: in the trigger tab you can make it run at a special event (Power-Troubleshooter with ID 1 for resume) to run it again.